# where is jruby/lib after install using rvm?

Tags: rvm, jruby

Using rvm, the installation of Jruby is trivial :

```
rvm install jruby
```

However, then I don't know where to find the jurby/lib where I'd like to add specific java jar (swt.jar for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install jruby as `rvm install jruby`, I believe it still installs 1.6.7.2, so you will find the lib directory under `~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rvm use jruby
Using /Users/asari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8
$ jruby -e 'p $:'
["/Users/asari/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8", "/Users/asari/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared", "/Users/asari/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8", "."]
```

You can always set your `$:` on the fly, e.g.,

```
$: << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib')
```